# What is the default Maximum Size for a Google Guava Cache?

Tags: guava

Given a Guava cache created with the code below is there a maximum cache size if one is not set?

```
LoadingCache<String, String> loadingCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String load(String key) throws Exception
    {
        return key.toUpperCase();
    }
});
```

In my case I really want a cache with no upper bound in size. I am using the cache to store permissions for logged in users and will evict items from the cache on user logout or session expiry.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The default cache is unbounded: as the [javadoc for CacheBuilder](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/24.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) explains

> These features are all optional

and

> By default cache instances created by CacheBuilder will not perform any type of eviction.

Comment: Great thanks for the link, I just found out about Guava yesterday and its been a lot of open tabs in my browser trying to gork it.

Comment: Did they remove the section regarding default `maximumSize` value? I can't locate any mention of it in newer javadocs, e.g.  http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html

Comment: @Henrik there's never been a section on a default `maximumSize` value: as implied by "These features are all optional", and more explicitly with "By default cache instances created by `CacheBuilder` will not perform any type of eviction", there is _no_ default value, hence no eviction.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is no limit, if your mean “default” is `CacheBuilder.maximumSize()` is never called.

And I don’t think your application needs size-based evict strategy. When user sessions expires, just remove it from cache (`Cache.invalidate(key)`).

And String upper case doesn't need cache, call upper case directly is much easier and effective than cache.